# How to Browse Server files using Flex4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I need to show the server uploaded files in flex 4.5 for a web application to manage the uploaded files like upload, delete and open for preview.

Can anyone help me How to list the sever side files in Flex action script3.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just let Flash player browse your server files. But you could create a workaround.
Make a script on the server which will give you the list of files located at the path you're looking for. Through basic POST you can ask for a list of files for a directory. Then you can display it in your flash side. But remember every actual action that happens to your files **MUST** happen on the serverside. Also **BEWARE** such things, because it's really easy to look up network requests that are made in browser, so you may end up with all of your files deleted one day. So make sure you implement some security stuff.

Comment: Thanks Gio, I want create the application like File Manager. So I have to call any service to fetch the file lists on the server folder directory?

Comment: Yeah I understand. Yes you should. There's no other way as far as I know. You should send a request to server to send you a list of files for example root directory. Then You'll parse this data and display in your SWF. After each click you must send a request. And this will be slow. So I don't recommend doing it in Flash.